# Email template attach images to email

Tags: email, zurb-foundation, html-email

I'm making a template for an email and I have some icons on it for Social, but when I send the email and I open it, the images are as attachements and I don't want that.

Is any way to fix it?
I'm designing the template with Fundation Email, Zurb.

Here a Screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Can you add the newsletter code?

Comment: Fixed it adding all the images with css, works well and supported for most of the email clients.

Comment: Post this comment as an answer then ;)